# How to understand the "Densely Connected Layer" section in tensorflow tutorial

Tags: tensorflow

In the [Densely Connected Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#convolution-and-pooling) section of the tensorflow tutorial, it says the image size is **7 x 7**, after it is been processed. I tried the code, and it seem these parameters works.

But I do not know how to get this **7 x 7** dimension. I understand that:

- the original image is 28 x 28,
- in the 1st conv layer, the `max_pool_2x2` function will reduce both of the image dimension by a factor of 4, so after the first pooling operation, the image size is **7 x 7**
- HERE'S WHAT I DO NOT UNDERSTAND

  in the 2nd conv layer, there another `max_pool_2x2` function call, so I think the image size should be reduce by a factor of 4 *again*. But actually did not.

Which step I got wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You also need to know the stride of the max pool and convolution.

```
def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Here, we can see that convolution has a stride of 1 and max pool has a stride of 2. How you can look at max pool, is that it takes a 2x2 box, and slides it over the image, each time taking the maximum value over 4 pixels. If you have a stride of 2, it takes 2 steps each time it moves! The image size should reduce by a factor of 2, instead of 4.

In other words, a 28x28 picture with max pool 2x2 and stride 2, will become 14x14. Another max pool 2x2 and stride 2 will reduce it to 7x7.

To further illustrate my point, let's take the case of max pool 2x2 and stride 1. If we don't pad the image, it will become a 27x27 image after max pool.

Here's an image for a more complete answer:
[image]

Comment: Ah~strid, I forgot to count that in. Thanks~

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Teach Yourself Deep Learning with TensorFlow](http://googleresearch.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/teach-yourself-deep-learning-with.html) and [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/me#!/)
 with Vincent Vanhoucke

This is covered in the course. I am currently working through it.

The course is free, however you do have to sign up. It is a series of videos, quizzes and coding projects all self paced and self graded. I am learning a lot and enjoy it.

Here is one of the quizzes.

[image]

Comment: That's course is on my TODO list, after my vacation plan :)

Comment: @GuyCoder did you still want to talk about the course?

Comment: I did it. I just had a hope that you know how to do that :)